# How to change the validation error text color in Sitecore forms?

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am working on Sitecore forms and implemented the forms. It is working fine. But I am facing difficulty in change the color of the validation error message. I need to change the validation error message to red color. How can I achieve this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write CSS for the error element and change the color to red.
Example (please update error css class to real class name):

```
span.error {
    color:red;
}
```